# Can a combination of sliding capacitor plates create a long lasting current?

Tags: energy-conservation, voltage, capacitance, batteries

[image]Can a combination of sliding capacitor plates create a long lasting current? Let say we can move easely the two negative plates from and towards the positive plate so when one is closer the other is farther, and the plates have enough capacity so when there is more voltage on the upper plate the current flows in one direction through the bulb and when the current stops and we reposition the plates there should be a current flow in the oposite direction...Should we lose a very small amount of energy by moving the plates to get current and light in the bulb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the *red* plate is charged (positive or negative but charged) and is also insulated from its environment so its total charge (not its distribution) stays constant, then moving the blue plates will induce a time varying surface charge on *all* the plates and a current through the load. The work expended in moving the plate will be dissipated in the load's resistance.

There are a couple of potential loss mechanisms even ignoring motional friction:

1. the field cannot be fully constrained between the plates, there
   is also a stray field that will induce charges on the surroundings,
   and the induced current will not be through the load;
2. if the back-and-forth motion is *very* fast then you will also incur
   radiation losses. Say, the motional frequency is $f$ and the linear
   dimensions and separation of the system is $\le \ell$ then to
   minimize the radiation losses you must also have $f\ell \ll  c$.